# Assigning properties based on string parameters

Tags: c#

I am using the below method to assign value to my object(Team.Driver/Team.Codriver). This works fine but just wanted to know if I could improve this code via LINQ or other options.

```
public void MoveDriverCodriver(
    Team source, string sourceType, Team target, string targetType) 
{
    if (sourceType == "Driver")
    {
        if (targetType == "Driver")
        {
            target.Driver = source.Driver;
        }
        else
        {
            target.Codriver = source.Driver;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (targetType == "Driver")
        {
            target.Driver = source.Codriver;
        }
        else
        {
            target.Codriver = source.Codriver;
        }
    } 
}
```

Also second part is I want to update target Driver/Codriver details with the appropriate source. But I want to retain the id's of target Driver/Codriver.

```
class Driver
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Firstname { get; set; }
  public string Lastname { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
}

class Team
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Driver Driver { get; set; }
  public Driver Codriver { get; set; }
}
```

calling move operation.

```
Team team1 = new Team(); //Do some operation on team1
Team team2 = new Team(); //Do some operation on team2
MoveDriverCodriver(team1, "Driver", team2, "Codriver"); //Here I am trying to assign team1's driver to team2's codriver.
```

Comment: Do you have specific reasons for not just doing `team2.Codriver = team1.Driver`?

Comment: This doesn't look very useful (yet). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet The MoveDriverCodriver method would be called multiple times as there are sequence of Driver and Codriver to be changed so I would need a method to do the moving for me.

Comment: @t3chb0t I am trying to move my Driver and Codriver between/within teams based on input received. Like Driver and Codriver can be assigned to different team and they could change from Driver to Codriver and vice-versa as well.Hope this clarifies my purpose.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Also team2.Codriver = team1.Driver would do a shallow copy for me but I want to achieve Deep copy as my Driver class has some reference objects(not in example above) and both team2.Codriver and team1.Driver should have different copies of these objects.

Comment: @KavyaShetty: there's no difference in behavior between your method and my suggestion: both perform a shallow copy. I still don't think it's clear why you need this method at all, but perhaps you could update your post with an example that shows how it's used in practice? There probably a better alternative (one that doesn't involve magic strings), but it's hard to tell without knowing how and why it's used.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I have updated my question to use Deepcopy utility which will be used in all my 4 cases.

Comment: @t3chb0t I just wanted to clarify that the assignment target.Driver = source.Driver; similarly others in the if checks are actually complex operations being performe like DeepCopyUtility.DeepCopy(source.Driver, target.Codriver, new[] {"Id"}); where deep copy of these objects take place as per previous comments doubts by Pieter. Also I have read the answer below which has reduced the source check but I am looking at the target check getting reduced as well.

Comment: @KavyaShetty: whether you do a shallow or a deep copy, both can easily be done in-line, so that doesn't explain why `MoveDriverCodriver` needs to exist. Can you give an example of what problem this method is trying to solve?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet My input payload has a list of operations like 1) Move Team 1 Driver to Team 2 Codriver 2) Move Team 3 Codriver to Team 4 Driver 3) Move Team 5 Driver to Team 5 Codriver. So I am trying to write a generic method capture these move operations also with each move there are some additional data that gets moved like Driver's income, property etc. These are again complex objects. My method will take care of these moves as well.

Answer (score 1):

Making the assumption you can't just use `team1.Driver = team2.Codriver` because you don't know the name of the properties first hand, I would build an even more generic function where it can be used with any type.

Also, I wouldn't name it Move because there is no move involved since the source still retains its values,

That said, my approach would be:

```
public void CopyProperty<T>(T source, string sourcePropertyName, T target, string targetPropertyName)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }

    if (target == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(target));
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourcePropertyName))
    {
        ThrowInvalidParameterNameException(nameof(sourcePropertyName));
    }

    if (targetPropertyName == null)
    {
        ThrowInvalidParameterNameException(nameof(targetPropertyName));
    }

    Type elementType = typeof(T);
    PropertyInfo sourceProperty = elementType.GetProperty(sourcePropertyName);
    if (sourceProperty == null)
    {
        ThrowPropertyDoesNotExistException(sourcePropertyName, nameof(sourcePropertyName), elementType.Name);
    }

    if (!sourceProperty.CanRead)
    {
        ThrowPropertyAccessException(sourcePropertyName, PropertyAccessType.Read);
    }

    PropertyInfo targetProperty = elementType.GetProperty(targetPropertyName);
    if (targetProperty == null)
    {
        ThrowPropertyDoesNotExistException(targetPropertyName, nameof(targetPropertyName), elementType.Name);
    }

    if (!targetProperty.CanWrite)
    {
        ThrowPropertyAccessException(targetPropertyName, PropertyAccessType.Write);
    }

    if (sourceProperty.PropertyType != targetProperty.PropertyType)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Concat("Property ", sourcePropertyName, " is not the same type as Property ", targetPropertyName));
    }

    targetProperty.SetValue(target, sourceProperty.GetValue(source, Type.EmptyTypes), Type.EmptyTypes);
}

private void ThrowInvalidParameterNameException(string parameterName)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid parameter name ", parameterName);
}

private void ThrowPropertyDoesNotExistException(string propertyParameter, string propertyParameterName, string typeName)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(string.Concat("Property ", propertyParameter, " does not exist in type ", typeName, " "), propertyParameterName);
}

private enum PropertyAccessType
{
    Read,
    Write
}

private void ThrowPropertyAccessException(string propertyParameter, PropertyAccessType accessType)
{
    throw new AccessViolationException(string.Concat("Property: ", propertyParameter, ", Access type: ", accessType));
}
```

With this you would get a safe and generic method to copy properties where you can use with any type and don't know which property is going to be copied **(does not account for indexed properties)**.

You can use it calling:

```
CopyProperty(team1, "Driver", team2, "Codriver");
```

There is no collections to query for (unless you are searching for the right property) so I don't see how you can use linq.

This however has more if's than your first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You could at least simplify the code as follows:

```
public static void MoveDriverCodriver(Team source, string sourceType, Team target, string targetType)
{     
  Driver sourceDriver = sourceType == "Driver" ? source.Driver : source.Codriver;
  if (targetType == "Driver")
  {
     target.Driver = sourceDriver;
  }
  else
  {
     target.Codriver = sourceDriver;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how you'd use LINQ for this, maybe someone else can chime in on that. On the other hand, readability is sometimes more important.

Answer (score -2):

Following is the change that I have done to simplify:-

```
public void MoveDriverCodriver(Team source, string sourceType, Team target, string targetType) 
{
    Move(sourceType == "Driver" ? source.Driver : source.Codriver, targetType == "Driver" ? target.Driver : target.Codriver);
}

public void Move(Driver source, Driver target) 
{
    source = target;
}
```

Comment: Test it, with code you show this has no effect.

Comment: The above code only answers how I improved my code to reduce my if else conditions.

Comment: The code in Move() has no effect, you're swapping LOCAL variables. Only.